# animating background position for multiple background images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here I am trying to create a background image slider by using jQuery slider by animating its background position.
Here is my html and CSS

```
<div id="sliderWrapper">

</div>

#sliderWrapper
{
    /*background-color: transparent;*/
    width: 620px;
    height: 349px; 
    background-image: url(images/1.png), url(images/2.jpg);
    background-position: 0px 0px, 620px 0px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat,no-repeat;
    background-size: cover,cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover,cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover,cover;        
}
$('#sliderWrapper').animate({
    'backgroundPosition':'-620px 0px,0px 0px'
}, 1500);
```

There animate of backgroundPosition is not working

I read in many blogs to use the following

```
    backgroundPositionX:'-640px';
```

It works fine with div having single background Images.  But I don't know how to work with div's having multiple background Images.

Comment: Could you please explain me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the alternate style in a CSS class, the transition also in the CSS, and just use scripting to toggle the class:

CSS

```
#test
{
    width: 620px;
    height: 349px; 
    background-image: url(image1.jpg), url(image2.jpg);
    background-position-x: 0px, 620px;
    background-position-y: 0px, 0px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat,no-repeat;
    background-size: cover,cover;
    transition: background-position-x 1.5s;
}

#test.test2 {
    background-position-x: -620px, 0px;

}
```

scripting:

```
$('#button').click(function () {
        $('#test').toggleClass('test2')
})
```

Answer (score 1):

One option would be use CSS3 transitions and add multiple images with ID's, like so:

#### HTML

```
<div id="bg_imgs">
    <img src="img1.jpg id="bg1" />
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
#bg_imgs { z-index: -1; /* places the DIV behind the default "layer" on content */ }
#img1 {
  -webkit-animation: myanim 5s infinite; /* Chrome, Safari 5+ */
     -moz-animation: myanim 5s infinite; /* Firefox 5-15 */
       -o-animation: myanim 5s infinite; /* Opera 12.00 */
          animation: myanim 5s infinite; /* Chrome, Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera 12.10+ */
}

@-webkit-keyframes myanim {
  0%   { opacity: 0.0; }
  50%  { opacity: 0.5; }
  100% { opacity: 1.0; }
}
@-moz-keyframes myanim {
  0%   { opacity: 0.0; }
  50%  { opacity: 0.5; }
  100% { opacity: 1.0; }
}
@-o-keyframes myanim {
  0%   { opacity: 0.0; }
  50%  { opacity: 0.5; }
  100% { opacity: 1.0; }
}
@keyframes myanim {
  0%   { opacity: 0.0; }
  50%  { opacity: 0.5; }
  100% { opacity: 1.0; }
}
```